# cocos 2d project cant convert to objective ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing a cocos2d game, I tried to converted the code to Objective c ARC,
But it shows some issues in the cocos 2d library.

How can I convert a cocos2d application to Objective C ARc.
Is there any new release of cocos2d which is ARC compatible,

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to post the errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable ARC on a file-by-file basis. For each element of the Cocos2D Library, apply the technique of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Err, for 50+ files this is painful.

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d-iphone v1.1 (beta) and 2.0 (beta) are compatible with ARC - **but only** if you build cocos2d-iphone into a static library. There's no official instructions or template project yet.

[Tiny Tim Games has a tutorial](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/) on that, and [Ray Wenderlich has an alternative solution](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6804/how-to-make-a-multi-directional-scrolling-shooter-part-1).

And [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) gives you ARC for cocos2d-iphone out of the box, plus all the [nitty-gritty information about ARC](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKDOC/Working+with+Automatic+Reference+Counting+%28ARC%29) that'll help you with the follow-up questions you'll have sooner than later.